# missing dependencies when updating parent state

Tags: reactjs

I have a React child implemented as:

```
const Section = ( {questions, header, index, addRT} ) => {
  const [average, setAverage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const valid_answers = questions.filter(({answer}) => answer !== 'N/A')
    let average2 = valid_answers.reduce((runningTotal, value) => {
            return runningTotal + (Math.floor(parseInt(value.answer)/5))*5
    }, 0)/valid_answers.length;
    setAverage(average2);
    addRT(average2);
  }, [])

  ...render here
}
```

and the parent implemented as:

```
function ProcessFile( props ) {
  let location = useLocation()
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({})
  const [runningTotal, setRunningTotal] = useState(0)
  const [file, setFile] = useState("")
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const addToRunningTotal = (sectionAverage) => {
        setRunningTotal((runningTotal) => runningTotal+sectionAverage)
    }
    
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ProcessFile->useEffect", location.pathname.slice(1))
    const getAnswers = async () => {
        setFile(location.pathname.slice(1).replace(/%20/gi," "))
        const response = await answerFileServer.getFile(location.pathname.slice(1))
        setAnswers(response);
    }
    getAnswers();
  }, [location.pathname])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{location.pathname.slice(1).replace(/%20/gi," ")}</h1>
          {Object.values(answers).map((section, index) => {
            return (
              <fieldset key={section.header}>
                <h2>{section.header}</h2>
                <Section key={section.header+"section"} 
                  questions={section.questions} 
                  header={section.header} 
                  index={index} 
                  addRT={(sectionAverage) =>{addToRunningTotal(sectionAverage)}}
                />
              </fieldset>
            )
          })}
          </div>
            {runningTotal.toFixed(3)}
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But I get the dreaded "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'addRT' and 'questions'." I've tried adding the dependencies as suggested and using different hooks. Either I get infinite rerenders or the runningTotal constantly accumulates.

When the parent calls the children with .map, the children should calculate their average and update the parent's runningTotal. I'd rather not disable the warning, how do I fix it?

Comment: Both average and running total should be derived instead of stateful, unless there is a something else that is also setting those values. For example, you can just have: `const = valid_answers.reduce((runningTotal, value) => {
            return runningTotal + (Math.floor(parseInt(value.answer)/5))*5
    }, 0)/valid_answers.length;`